# Auto Advance Tag Time

Tags: html

I don't really know how to ask this question but my question is how to make the following auto advance tag replace the time before auto advancing (in this code it is 5 seconds {content="5;} ) with the text from a .txt file. Here is the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=test.htm">
```

Comment: So you want to replace the `5` in the `meta content` with content from a `.txt` file? That **cannot** be done in raw HTML. You would need a server-side language such as PHP that would build the `<meta>` tag based on a server-side variable.

Comment: How would I do that I am not real good with PHP. :/